# $f$ is a multiple of $g$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $Z(f) \supset Z(g)$

Tags: general-topology, ideals, topological-groups, principal-ideal-domains

An idea $I$  in $C(X)$  is called $z$-ideal  if $Z(f) \in Z(I) $ implies $f \in I$.

$Z(f) =\{x \in X : f(x) = 0 \}$

**Can you help me to prove these problems?**

> Let $X$ be a finite discrete space in $C(X)$.
>
> 1: $f$ is a multiple of $g$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $Z(f) \supset Z(g)$
>
> 2: Every ideal is a $z$-ideal.
>
> 3: Every ideal is principal, and , in fact, is generated by  an
>   idempotent.

Comment: Is $C(X)$ the space of continuous functions on $X$ as an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @ Stressed- out $C(X)$ is the space of  real continuous function on topological space $X$, so that $C(X) \subset \mathbb{R}^{X} $

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $X = \{1,\ldots,m\}$, say, that $C(X)$ is just $\mathbb{R}^m$ in the ring structure of pointwise addition and multiplication. Any real function on $X$ is continuous and is uniquely described by the $m$-tuple of its values.

So if $Z(f) \supseteq Z(g)$, we define $h(i) = 0$ for $i\in Z(g)$, $h(i) = \frac{f(i)}{g(i)}$ for $ i \notin Z(g)$. Then $f = h \cdot g$ in $C(X)$. The other direction is always true: if $f = h\cdot g$ for some $h \in C(X)$, $g(x) = 0$ implies $f(x) = 0$ so that $Z(g) \subseteq Z(f)$.

That every $I$ is a $z$-ideal also follows: let $Z(f) = Z(g)$ for some $g \in I$, then by (i) implies $f$ is a multiple of $g$, so $f \in I$ as required.

To see that every ideal is principal: let $I \subseteq C(X)$ be a proper ideal, 
then consider $Z[I] = \{Z(f) : f \in I\}$. This is a family of subsets of the finite $X$ that is closed under finite intersections and enlargements. If $Z(f) = \emptyset$ then $f$ is a unit and so cannot be in $I$, so $\emptyset \notin Z[I]$.
So $Z[I]$ is a filter on a finite set $X$, so $Z[I] \ni K= \cap Z[I] \neq \emptyset$. Then the function $g$ that is $0$ on $K$ and $1$ outside of $K$ is an idempotent that generates $I$. ($f \in I$ means $Z(g) =K \subseteq Z(f)$ so $f$ is a multiple of $g$. That $g \in I$ is because $I$ is a $z$-ideal.